# Can package object be defined somehow so that its apply is called using a syntactic sugar?

Tags: scala, package

Let us have two sources:

`Library/package.scala`:

```
package object Library {
  def apply(name: String) = name.reverse
}
```

`Main.scala`:

```
object Main extends App {
  println(Library.apply("reverse me")) // works
  println(Library("reverse me")) // error: package Library is not a value
}
```

Is there some way around this? Can I add something into the package object or someplace else so that I can call the object directly using the syntactic sugar, without having to specify apply explicitly?

Comment: Why a `package object`?

Comment: I am adapting quite large source base converted from a different language. There already exists a package `Library` containing many objects and there also exists a value `Library` which is accessed (as a Map) to obtain individual objects.

Comment: It doesn't comply with the usual coding convention for Scala code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting it occurred to me I can use an auxiliary object with the same name but enclosed in a different package or object, like this:

```
object LibraryApply {
  object Library {
    def apply(name: String) = _root_.Library.apply(name)
  }
}
import LibraryApply._
```